# Android Profile image resizing and cropping option facebook

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview

I am working on a project in which I need to pick an image using image picker intent and then give option to user to crop it like facebook so that he can make it a profile picture. Image picker in done. But i wonder how can i give this crop option to user in android. What I need is , after selecting an image a rectangular box (like facebook) appears and user can crop , resize image and then save it. It their any help or library available for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Cropper](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper) for this purpose.